# Seemingly inconsistent Chrome XPath results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, namespaces, webkit, xpath

I have a very simple XML document that I've retrieved from a larger parent. See 'accountxml' below:

```
<accounts xmlns=​"https:​/​/​domain.com/path">​
    <customerid>​sometext</customerid>​
    <login>​sometext​</login>​
    <companyname>​sometext​</companyname>​
    <canmanageclients>​sometext</canmanageclients>​
</accounts>​
```

Simple enough - just one namespace URL (the URL referred to as ns2 in myNS namespace map below). Querying login:

```
accountxml.evaluate('//ns2:login',accountxml,myNS,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
```

returns OK:

```
<login>sometext</login>​
```

But:

```
accountxml.evaluate('//ns2:customerid',accountxml,myNS,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
```

Returns:

```
null
```

This is such a simple query I'm surprised it breaks. But I can reproduce it 100% of the time. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Chrome?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it isn't a case-related issue ? Like `customerid` being `customerID` ?

Comment: Gael: you're right. The small document above is printed exactly as the JS console sees it. But the larger parent it is taken from uses initialLowerCase for the element names. Even though I'm querying the smaller fragment, I still need to use the casing of the parent rather than the casing of the child. Want to pop an answer below?

Comment: I'm not seeking reputation, I'm actually happy I could solve your problem since I know nothing about xpath and wild-guessed my answer :D

Comment: @Gael: fair enough. I've expended on the cause & solution below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Gael for encouraging me to look at capitalization again.

The key to this is the document is taken from a larger parent. Although the small document above is printed **exactly** as the JS console sees it - with all element names in lower case, the larger parent it is taken from uses initialLowerCase for the element names.

**Even though I'm querying the smaller fragment, I still need to use the casing of the parent rather than the casing of the child.**

```
accountxml.evaluate('//ns2:customerId',accountxml,myNS,XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,null).singleNodeValue;
```

I'm not sure if this is a Chrome bug or an expected behavior.

Comment: That depends on the way you define `accountxml`: if you built it by an XML parser, then it's a bug because it should preserve the QName as it is expected be the XPath engine. If you didn't do it in that way, it was a bad design choice.

Comment: @Alejandro: Original full-tree XMLDocument was built with domParser. Then an XPath query ran. The first XPathResult was serialized to a string, then parsed from that string to create a new XMLDocument with just the branch in question.